# How to use .slice in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got this in my app

```
...
Score.find({ match: {$in: ids}} )
     .sort([[score_sort, 'descending']])
     .slice([skip, limit])
     .exec(function(err, scores) {
    if (err || !scores) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        // do something cool
    }
});
```

But I get an error using the slice operation, the error is:

```
Error: slice() must be used after where() when called with these arguments
```

I have tried to replace .find with .where but I still get the same error. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: My guess would be `Score.find().where({ match: {$in: ids}}).slice()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...

```
Score.find({ match: {$in: ids}} )
     .sort([[score_sort, 'descending']])
     .skip(skip)
     .limit(limit)
     .exec(function(err, scores) {
    if (err || !scores) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        // do something cool
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

`slice()` requires a `path` specified, which can be set either in an earlier `where()` call or within the `slice()` call itself.  [From the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-slice):

```
query.slice('comments', 5)
// or...
query.where('comments').slice(5)
```

Basically you need to state *what* you are slicing.  It's not clear from your example, but imagine your `Score` model has an array of `players` -- you could use `slice()` to only return the first 5 players from each `score` via:

```
Score.find().slice('players', 5).exec(function(err, scores) {
...
```

Comment: I just want to limit the numbers of scores I get from Score.find(..) and skip some of them. If my find call finds 100 scores, I might only want the scores from 25 to 50. Is there something else then .slice to use? I have used .limit() before to limit the number of scores I get.

Comment: I use scores = scores.slice(skip, skip+limit); to get the functionality I want. Is there anything simular in mongoose.

Comment: Score.find({ match: {$in: ids}} )
.sort([[score_sort, 'descending']])
.skip(skip)
.limit(limit)
.exec(function(err, scores) {
 // something cool
}
seems to work as I thought .limit([skip, limit]) worked

Comment: Yes, in that case, you'd use `limit` and `skip`, for example: `query.skip(100).limit(20)` [from the mongoose API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip)