# Mongoose populate options limit, how to limit number of sub document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query to find an account and populate sub doc of the account.

When I use populate path:"orders" the limit option will work. But if I use populate path"orders.order", the option limit will not work.

What should I do?

My schema is like:

```
  var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    _id:id,
    orders:{type:[{
      order:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Order'}
    }]}
  });


var findOrderByUserId = function(accountId,index,count,callback){
  var limit = index*count;
  console.log(limit);
  Account.findOne({_id:accountId}).populate({
    path:'orders.order',//If path is orders, then limit will work

    options:{
      limit:limit
    }
  }).exec(function (err, doc) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
              }
              console.log(doc);
                var array = [];
                for(var i=limit - count;i<doc.orders.length;i++){
                    if(doc.orders[i]!=null){
                        array.push(doc.orders[i]);            
                    }
                    else{
                      break;
                    }
                }
              callback(doc);
          })
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with mongoose, but in order to limit the number of sub-docs we use the `$slice` operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411493/how-to-use-slice-in-mongoose

Comment: Thank you, I think you can answer the question rather than post comment :)

Comment: I'm too lazy to right an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`limit` works only with top level documents, to control arrays inside a document you need to use `$slice`, so that means you need to rebuild your query, like this (mongo shell):

```
db.posts.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: 5 } } )
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24419736/5919473)  for more info - and example:

```
query.slice('comments', 5)
// or...
query.where('comments').slice(5)
```

[manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Comment: Your posts could use a bit of formatting otherwise great answers :)

Answer (score 4):

To whom may also concern this question, I noticed a tricky thing about slice when using mongoose population.

for example, we have two Models called UserGroupModel and UserModel

```
var UserGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'}],
    groupName:String
})

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String
})
```

and now we want to populate User in UserGroup, and for performance consideration, we only want the last, let's say 20, of all the users.

here, code like this won't work

```
UserGroupModel.findById(userGroupId)
    .populate('users', 'username')
    .slice('users', -20)
    .select('users')
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, group){})
```

you'll notice that the slice function did not work

and you have to change to

```
UserGroupModel.findById(userGroupId)
    .populate('users', 'username')
    .slice('users', -20)
    .select('-groupName')
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, group){})
```

the main point is **If you want to do slice with population, you have to use exclusion**

PS."mongoose":"4.4.15"