# How to limit the populate of a particular object inside the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my mongoose schema contains two objects one is a type Number and other is Id references of another schema in form of array.
i need to get first 5 populated docs from the array and print them.

Schema 1 --

```
GantryId: {
    type:Number,
    required:true
},
PassDetails:[{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Pass'
}]
```

this is a test data in the Schema -

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d1c45cdb402da8b0db37850"),
"GantryId" : 1,
"PassDetails" : [
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab3e"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab3f"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab40"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab42"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab43"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab41"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab44"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab47"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab45"),
    ObjectId("5d1c45c88e8d321db85aab46")
]
```

i need the first 5 populated docs as an output.

Comment: what do you mean by populated ids, do you want the populated docs or just first 5 ids?

Comment: This may help https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403126/3284355